# Using pandas to shift data to new column without loosing it's position

Tags: pandas

Hi so I currently have a lot of data (660,000 lines) that looks like this.

[image]

However, I'm hoping to make it look something like this

[image]

where anything named Async Serial is put to the side. Currently I have code that looks like

```
asyncdata=data[data['name'].str.contains('Async Serial')]
midmsg = data[data['name'].str.contains('mid recieve')]
newmsg=pd.concat([midmsg,asyncdata],axis=1)
```

But this just puts all the Async Serial stuff to the bottom rather than embedded between.
I also tried for-looping and placing everything in newmsg that way, but there is so much data that it takes over 2 hours to process (I actually don't know how long it takes I stopped the program after 2 hours and it wasn't done processing). Does anyone know of a shorter quicker process?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the output after you have placed all the `Async Serial` records in those new columns? If you could describe what the end goal is you have in mind, there might be a better way to solve for this outside of restructuring the data in this way.

Comment: So I want to compare the data sent from async Serial and data from the mid receive that have the same (or very close to the same time). Unfortunately they aren't exactly the same time so it makes this a little complicated

Answer (score 0):

If your data in pandas, they have index. You need sort they after concat.
Try it:

```
asyncdata = data[data['name'].str.contains('Async Serial')]
midmsg = data[data['name'].str.contains('mid recieve')]
newmsg = pd.concat([midmsg, asyncdata], axis=1).sort_index()
print(newmsg)
```